# What is the relationship between various groups

Tags: lie-groups, projective-geometry, projective-space, projective-module

Does the projective linear group of a given dimension share a representation with a group of automorphisms?

Comment: The projective linear group of a vector space is the quotient of the general group by its center, which over a field (or a division ring) is the set (subgroup) of all non-zero scalar matrices...is this what you have in mind? And now, what do you mean by "sharing" a representation?

Comment: The projective linear group $PGL(n+1)$ is the group of automorphisms of the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^n$ (as an algebraic variety).

Comment: Or, $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ are the holomorphic automorphisms of the Riemann sphere.

Comment: @DonAntonio I am wondering if nxn matrices represent a subgroup of some group of automorphisms besides representing the projective transformations. If that doesn't make any sense, its probably cause I don't know what I am saying :s

Comment: @AlexYoucis do you know a similar result for real projective plane?

Comment: @JonathanFischof, all the **invertible** $\,n\times n\,$ matrices over some field $\,F\,$ represent all the automorphisms of the linear space $\,F^n\,$ over $\,F\,$ (i.e., all the invertible operators over that linear space).